# Matlab: how to optimize a code to find postfix in a sting

Tags: regex, string, matlab, optimization

I have a cell `106x1` of strings `TrajCompact`. In every string I want to find all the prefix that are combination of `(0,1,2,3,4)` and consider only the postfix after this prefix My prefix are:

> 00,01,02,03,04,10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,23,24,30,31,32,33,34,40,41,42,43,44

I try to do this, using the code

```
for k=1:size(TrajCompact,1)
    matches(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k), '\(?00.*', 'match', 'once');
end
```

The code run but I have to write it 25 times: one for every prefix. I want to find a compact expression so I modify the code in this way:

```
[digits{1:2}] = ndgrid(0:4);
for k=1:106
    matches(k) = regexp(TrajCompact(k), sprintf('?%d%d.*', digits{1}(k), digits{2}(k)), 'match', 'once');
end
```

but it doesn't make what I want, what is the flaw here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve the problem inside the `regexp`:

```
matches{k} = regexp(TrajCompact{k}, '\(?[0-4][0-4].*', 'match', 'once');
```

**Later Edit**

Based on a longer discussion in the comments of this post, the solution for OPs problem should lie along the lines of using the function:

```
get_matches = @(x,c)cellfun(@(s)regexp(s,sprintf('\\(%s\\)[0-4]+',x),'match'),c,'UniformOutput',false);
```

For example, for the string cell:

```
str_cell = {'(23)2' '02(13)(23)1(23)21(23)20(23)1(23)21(23)1(23)(13)(23)1(32)31(32)12321(23)21321(23)132(31)(32)31(32)12321(23)21(23)21(23)20(23)2' '210432342432132342(34)323134(32)43413243424321234321432412343212(34)1341234' '24321(34)(32)3432134(32)3431(34)323432(34)(32)3432(34)3'};
```

the matched strings may be retrieved as:

```
a23 = get_matches('23', str_cell);
a23 = [a23{:}];
```

Looping over possible "prefixes" is trivial.

Comment: I try your line of code but it gives me an error: 'Undefined function 'regexp' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @Ely That means your cell array of strings `TrajCompact` is not actually a cell array of strings. Most likely you have empty cells in the form `[]` (double) rather than `''` (char).

Comment: I have correct the mistake: the code run but it gives me only the postfix of 04,40... not all the others!

Comment: @Ely That means that you have only '04' or '40' prefixed strings in `TrajCompact`. I have verified the script for other cases, and it detects e.g. `'(32abc)'` with no problems.

Comment: It's strange because my strings have other prefix. There is a way to link my cell array of strings? So, i can show it to you

Comment: @Ely type `TrajCompact{:}` at your Command Window, then paste some of the output.

Comment: Example of strings 
'(23)2'

'02(13)(23)1(23)21(23)20(23)1(23)21(23)1(23)(13)(23)1(32)31(32)12321(23)21321(23)132(31)(32)31(32)12321(23)21(23)21(23)20(23)2'

'210432342432132342(34)323134(32)43413243424321234321432412343212(34)1341234'

'24321(34)(32)3432134(32)3431(34)323432(34)(32)3432(34)3'

Comment: That's a single string (i.e. a single cell element?) or are the strings merged?

Comment: @Ely All of these strings are matches. Did you get a different result?

Comment: the strings are 106 like the cells, every cell has a string: i have problems to past all; i post examples of single cell elements: '(23)2' cell1,   '02(13)(23)1(23)21(23)20(23)1(23)21(23)1(23)(13)(23)1(32)31(32)12321(23)21321(23‌​)132(31)(32)31(32)12321(23)21(23)21(23)20(23)2' cell2,  '24321(34)(32)3432134(32)3431(34)323432(34)(32)3432(34)3'  cell3

Comment: @Ely Yes, I got it. But all these strings are matches for your pattern, so they are returned as such. Did you get a different answer? Or did you expect a different answer?

Comment: @CTS-link When I use your code, it doesn't find the prefix in this strings.

Comment: @Ely Of course it doesn't find only the prefixes. Regexp matches the entire string, so you get back the entire string. And you match the string once, so -- again, -- you get the entire string back as fast as it found one match. For example, in the string `(23)345(12)222`, what is the expected output? I'm trying to understand what you want as result, but you must come up with something more consistent than "it doesn't work". :-)

Comment: I try to explain better: TrajCompact is a cell array 106x1, every cell has a string. I have to find the 25 combination of 0,1,2,3,4 in these strings '00', '01', '02' etc. At the begin I use this code 'matches = regexp(TrajCompact, '\(?01.*', 'match', 'once');' and I change '01' with the 25 combination. I want to find a way to optimize the code: my 'ideal code' has to find for every combination the postfixs of every strings and save them in a matrix or in a cell array. For the moment if I use the previous my code, matches is empty; with your code I have the same problem:  matches is empty.

Comment: @Ely So, to answer my own question :-) for the input string `(23)345(12)222` there should be two outputs, `345` and `222` (yes/no)?

Comment: In this string (23)345(12)222 if i search '23', I attend in matches 345(12)222; if i search (12), I attend in matches 222. Both in my code and your code, matches is empty.

Comment: And if the string is `(12)222(12)ABC` and you search for `(12)`, do you want only the first occurrence, or all of them?

Comment: All of them but I don't have strings with letters, only numbers from zero to 4. I try an other solution but It gives me always the same problem. I post it [digits{1:2}] = ndgrid(0:4);
for k=1:25
matches(:,k) = regexp(TrajCompact, sprintf('?%d%d.*', digits{1}(k), digits{2}(k)), 'match', 'once');
end

Comment: @Ely I updated the answer. Looping trough all the possibilities is trivial, also eliminating the first 4 chars from the matched strings. I hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Ely Also I would recommend updating your question so it reflects clearly the requirements. Your question can be thus useful to other people that are having similar issues. But that is only if you want to.